# Руханка чи зарядка?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники

На сайті [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/inshe/ruxanka) є цікава каринка

[image]

В ЗМІ також часто вживають саме слово "руханка" для означення виконання фізичних вправ, замість звичного слова "зарядка".

Проте в СУМ слова "[руханка](http://sum.in.ua/s/rukhanka)" немає, а є лише "[зарядка](http://sum.in.ua/s/zarjadka)"

> 3. Фізичні вправи, які виконуються з метою оздоровлення організму

Слово "руханка" є в таких словниках [Орфографічний словник української мови,](http://slovopedia.org.ua/35/53408/188113.html) 
[Словар українського сленгу,](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53408/375742.html) [ВТССУМ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53408/979614.html), [Лексикон львівський](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53408/1066686.html)

Якому слово варто надти перевагу вживання в офіційному мовлені?

Comment: Відео на каналі "Твоя підпільна гуманітарка" із посиланням на це питання :) https://youtu.be/DOfBps2uLrA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заперечую. В [СУМ-20](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) вже цілком можливо, що є або буде слово руханка:

> **РУ́ХАНКА**
>
> Гімнастика, фізичні вправи.
>
> Приклади:
>
> То Наталка прала на річці. Запнута кулинкою, орудувала на сонці над водою, як вправний
> спортсмен на вранішній **руханці**. (І. Багряний)
>
> “Як я маю зайвий час, читаю радо, графине”. “І добре робите, мій пане, сказав доктор. –
> Філософія – це гімнастика мозку, **руханка**, як тепер говорять. (Б. Лепкий)

Так само у корпусі знаходимо 502 результати на слово [руханка](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac14_full&tab=advanced&keyword=%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0&attrs=word%2Ctag&viewmode=sen&attr_allpos=kw&refs_up=1&shorten_refs=0&itemsPerPage=500&structs=s%2Cg&refs=doc%2C%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.authTrans%2C%3Ddoc.born&default_attr=lemma&showresults=1&f_tab=advanced&c_customrange=1&operations=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22iquery%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%22%2C%22active%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22queryselector%22%3A%22iqueryrow%22%2C%22iquery%22%3A%22%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A7540%7D%5D), його використовують Вільде, Самчук, Рубчак, Тарнавський, Москалець, Дереш й інші.

До того ж, у "[зарядки](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=32181&page=1041)" значення "фізичні вправи" — друге, а в "руханки" — перше.

Можете використовувати те слово, яке вам більше до вподоби. Я особисто віддаю перевагу саме руханці.

В офіційному мовленні варто використовувати "зарядка", аж доки не пересвідчимось, що в СУМ-20 слово "руханка" вже нормативне.

Comment: Відео на каналі "Твоя підпільна гуманітарка" із посиланням на це питання :) https://youtu.be/DOfBps2uLrA